# Unable to navigate to a new view using navigation link in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

is anybody able to see why I am unable to navigate to a new view I have created called "FavouritesView" using NavigationLink?

this is the code of the HomeView where I am navigating from

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("test")
            .font(.title.bold())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                NavigationLink {
                    FavouritesView()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "doc.badge.gearshape")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
```

all I'm doing is putting in a navigation link at the top right next to the title

[image: top right icon]. just want to tap and goto my other view. Probably something im missing here anyone know the fix ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `VStack` in a `NavigationView` like so:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("test")
                .font(.title.bold())
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                    NavigationLink {
                        FavouritesView()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "doc.badge.gearshape")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.trailing, 20)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
```

And if you're using `Xcode 14 beta`, use the new `NavigationStack` for a more Advanced implementation. See [this.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/)

Comment: thanks, anyway round not using navigation view as was hoping to make it more custom when i get the favourites view?   IE no back button ect

Comment: think I've definitely seen it without using a navigation view

Comment: Unfortunately you can't navigate without it, it's been this way since SwiftUI first started. To hide the back button use .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

Comment: strange ive definately had this working without using NavigationView in another app ive created, using enviromentObjects.